# Maximum safe wattage for solenoid and duty time

Tags: power-supply, solenoid

[image]Please can somebody put my mind at rest?

I work on a machine that is unpowered until fully assembled and it has a push-pull solenoid (195222-237).

It has become apparent that we need to cycle this solenoid In order to allow setup of a vacuum gate (the solenoid keeps locking while we are trying to set it up).

I purchased a plug in 24 V PSU adapter rated at 1 A (24 V) and cut off the jack connector then made a rudimentary connection to the solenoid and it pulls! :)

This was a success, however I am worried that the wattage may damage the solenoid if left on too long.

Please can someone advise what the maximum duty time would be with this power supply? Ideally we would be able to leave it on for 2-3 minutes at a time.

If this is not possible is there a discrete inline resistor of something I can connect to the cable to allow the duty required?

[24 V Power Supply Adapter for Hypervolt Portable Massage Gun, with ON OFF Switch, 110-240V AC to DC 24 Volt 1A PSU DC Connector.](https://amzn.eu/d/e6Bukk3)

[Solenoid datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://docs.rs-online.com/fa1e/0900766b81634a3c.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwifqseP88uCAxVqgf0HHQ5XD8kQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3NyOgZX7IIzQb__WNclvRx)

Answer (score 0):

Datasheet says it can operate continuously; a power supply can supply power up to a limit but it’s rare you supply too much current to the load (unless it’s through the load) since in a sense the component is what is driving the wattage not the powersupply

components usually blow because either it continues to pull more electrons through it with more energy (leds usually) or a downstream component pulls more electrons through the component and overloads it

Comment: So do you think it's ok for me to use the PSU adaptor as a hack to operate the solenoid and safe to leave ON for a few minutes at a time?

Comment: should be, as far as I can tell based on my understanding of the circuit (it’s just a single solenoid attached to the power supply?)

Comment: Hi again, Actually no, the solenoid connects to a small L-pcb via a 2 way connector, then there is a small circuit track to an 8 wire loom, there are other small devices on the circuit but they connect to different wires than the two wires I intend to send 24v. Can I send you a drawing or something, I can't see a way to upload a image on here :(

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful here btw

Comment: would need a drawing to interpret readily, but assuming it’s not in series it will probably be ok

Comment: By the way, @DerickRoche, you can edit your original question if you are trying to upload an image since this would be supplemental clarification material.

Comment: Drawing uploaded. So I'm going to have to operate the solenoid via the loom off the back off the PCB. There are two pins on that loom that connect back to the solenoid connector. So the only additional circuitry is some copper track in the PCB which are isolated from the other devices on the board

Comment: *it’s rare you supply too much current to the load (unless it’s through the load)* How does that work out?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: @MiNiMe the load having another load after it in series

Comment: Ok so you think it would be ok?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, now the load isn't the load, but another load is? If you have two energy consumers in series, they behave as one load, and one current will flow through them both.

Comment: @MiNiMe I worded it badly, yes it would behave as one load but if a component after that solenoid manages to physically overload it and break it then it would fail (a solenoid is just a coil of wires after all, and at some point it will strain it)

Comment: Ok I'm confused now, maybe it would just be safer if I use the PSU to disengage the solenoid for brief periods (2-3 seconds at a time) this will still help me set up the gate valve but will just be a bit of a pain as leaving it for a few minutes at a time would be better

Comment: There are no other things in series with the solenoid, so lets drop the 'too much current' theory.

Comment: Yay or nay guys? 

Answer (score 0):

The [195222-237 Saia-Burgess Linear Solenoid, 24 V dc, 3.5N](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/linear-solenoids/4317510) [datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/49a7/A700000007975175.pdf) has the following performance data:

[image]

Where the part number breakdown is:

[image]

Which means the `195222-237` has a 37 awg coil which is rated a 23.8 VDC (nom), and with a 24 V dc supply has a maximum ON time of *infinity*.

The datasheet contains the following about a recommended heatsink:

> **Recommended Minimum Heat Sink** : Maximum watts dissipated by solenoid are based on an unrestricted flow of air at 20°C, with solenoid mounted on the equivalent of an aluminium plate measuring 51 mm square by 3.2 mm thick

The question was:

> This was a success, however I am worried that the wattage may damage the solenoid if left on too long.

Is the recommended heat sink fitted to the solenoid to allow for the 4 W dissipation when used with a 24 V dc supply?

I'm not sure how quickly the temperature will rise if 24 V dc is left applied and an insufficient heat sink. The datasheet doesn't seem to specify the maximum working temperature.

Comment: I can't add a heatsink to the solenoid unfortunately, its sort of floating in a small shaft and kept in place by a plate at the rear that has an o-ring on it. Minimal metal to metal contact really :(

Answer (score 0):

Not likely, 24V^2/141Ω (the resistance of the solenoid) yields ~4W  which is the rated value. It would be unusual to have a solenoid that could not operate continuously.

However the datasheet suggests it needs a heatsink:

> Maximum watts dissipated by solenoid are based on an unrestricted flow
> of air at 20°C, with solenoid mounted to the equivalent of an aluminum
> plate measuring 51mm square by 3.2mm thick

Another thing that you could try is use a [hit an hold strategy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373772/how-do-i-use-a-hit-and-hold-circuit-with-a-solenoid/373773#373773) which activates the solenoid with a higher voltage but then uses a lower voltage to hold (holding takes lower energy). This strategy would only work if the solenoid has a higher activation energy, consult with the manufacturer or conduct testing.

Comment: Hi, yes that would be PWM control I guess, the solenoid is controlled via PWM in final test however we do not have the option to do this during assembly and setup

Comment: Not PWM control, its off on, just with two different channels

Comment: Ah I see. Ok well either way I don't really have the option to do what you say. I was hoping this cheap PSU adaptor would do the job for what I need. :(